# What is goolge drive API?

Tags: rest, google-api, google-drive-api

Can anyone give me an overview about  google drive API, please?

- What are its abilities?
- What are its drawbacks?
- How is access obtained?

I searched about it but,don't understand any things.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. These kind of questions are off-topic. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Using Google drive API like any API, you can send request to Authenticate, do some thing or get data.
In case of google drive you can upload, download, rename ,share files more and more.
to find all possibilities have a look on this link (look at the left pane):
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk

Answer (score 0):

It helps you save, read and sync files stored in your Google Drive account directly from an app. For example: if you want to save a file from an application and don't want to store it on your mobile, you can store it in Google Drive. Likewise if you want to upload a file to an app or just see a file from Drive in you app.

Here are the steps to enable the Drive API for your project: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/enable-sdk

Answer (score 0):

[Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk) is a [REST API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) gives you a group of APIs along with client libraries, language-specific examples, and documentation to help you develop apps that integrate with Drive.

The core functionality of Drive apps is to download and upload files in Google Drive. Think of the drive api as simply a file store.  The information you have avalaibe is only the information about the files themselves.   Name, size, type ... drive api also contains the information about sharing files and who last accessed the file.  The Drive api also has a limited ablity to conert files from one type to another.  The google drive api does **NOT** give you the ability to edit the continence of the files.    The google sheets api does however give you the ability to edit a google sheet but that is a different api.

**Access**

The information available on Google drive api is private user data.  That means that in order to access that data you must have the permission of the user who owns it.   Gaining this permission is most often done though Oauth2 where by the application in question request the users consent to access the data.

**Libraries**

If you are considering developing an application to use the Google Drive api I recommend that you look for a client library in your chosen language.  The client libraries are designed to help you develop your application quickly.  There is normally a lot of documentation found for the different libraries.  You can find a number of [quickstarts](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk) within the documentation.